# deepstream.io List subscribe() not triggering

Tags: javascript, events, server, notifications, deepstream.io

using **deepstream.io: 3.1.1** and **deepstream.io-client-js: 2.3.0** updates on List are not propagating when using `list.addEntry('some-id')`, instead to get notifications of changes I must use `list.setEntries([..., 'some-id'])`

example:

**client 1**: *(after connecting and authenticating with server)*

```
cars = deepstreamClient.record.getList('cars/all')
```

**client 2**: *(after connecting and authenticating with server)*

```
cars = deepstreamClient.record.getList('cars/all')
cars.subscribe(console.log)
```

now *client 2* will print all changes to cars list, for instance:

**client 1**: `cars.setEntries(['porche','ferrari','bmw'])` makes **client 2** print `['porche','ferrari','bmw']`.

However simply adding an item to the `cars` list in **client 1**: `cars.addEntry('audi')` only changes the `cars` list in **client 1**; **client 2** is unaware of the change and no notification is triggered.